# Is it possible to add PostGIS to PipelineDB?

Tags: ubuntu, pipelinedb

Os:ubuntu 14.04 64bit

I'm trying to connect QGIS with pipelineDB. Homepage says it supports postGIS, but I couldn't find way to do it.

Older version has something like "loading PipelineDB extensions" during its init period while the 0.9.1 version I installed didn't have any.

Typing

"CREATE EXTENSION postgis;"

in psql doesn't work either giving such line as

could not access file "$libdir/postgis-2.1"

Is there some way to do such a thing? Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 2):

PostGIS is no longer pre-bundled with PipelineDB binaries. You will have to build and install it from source. We have a PipelineDB compatible [fork](https://github.com/pipelinedb/postgis) of PostGIS on our GitHub. Check out the tag for the appropriate release, in your case the following should work:

```
git clone -b 0.9.0 https://github.com/pipelinedb/postgis.git
```

After that you can follow the instruction is the `README.md` file found [here](https://github.com/pipelinedb/postgis/blob/pipeline-0.9.0/README.md).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to make thank for such help since I was in a hurry backthen. I'm sorry for late response and I'm really saved by your help.

Comment: So their docs are incorrect? http://docs.pipelinedb.com/builtin.html, I see blog post stating this here https://www.pipelinedb.com/blog/pipelinedb-0-8-6